# Apache Ignite: type substitution on serialization

Tags: ignite

I have a class `A`, a cache `A_CACHE` and a proxy object `AProxy extends A`. My goal is to serialize `AProxy` objects as if they are `A` objects (automatically substitute type) and put them into `A_CACHE`.
Is there any way in Apache Ignite to substitute type of an object that I am trying to put into cache (serialize using BinarySerializer)? 
What I have tried so far.
I have implemented and registered the same `BinarySerializer` for both types. I have also tried to play with `BinaryNameMapper` class to return the same class name for both classes, but without success. The only option that comes to my mind now is to use `BinaryObjectBuilder`. Is it really **the only** option for me?

Answer (score 0):

After a small research the solution was found.
`AProxy` should implement `writeReplace` method of `Serializable` interface. Return proxied instance from this method. If proxied class is `Serializable` or `Externalizable` and one wants to apply custom serialization, than `Binarylizable` interface should be implemented by proxied class (custom binary serializers are not applied when using the hack above, but instead `OptimizedMarshaller` is being used).